# how I can overcome this error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char []'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <cstring>

void initialize(char[],int*);
void input(const char[] ,int&);
void print ( const char*,const  int);
void growOlder (const char [], int* );

bool comparePeople(const char* ,const int*,const char*,const int*);

int main(){

  char name1[25];
     char name2[25];
     int age1; 
  int age2;


 initialize (name1,&age1);
 initialize (name2,&age2);

 print(name1,age1);
 print(name2,age2);

 input(name1,age1);
 input(name2,age2);

 print(name1,age1);
 print(name2,age2);

 growOlder(name2,&age2);

 if(comparePeople(name1,&age1,name2,&age2))
    cout<<"Both People have the same  name and age "<<endl;
 return 0;
}

void input(const  char name[],int &age)
{
 cout<<"Enter a name :";
 cin>>name ;

 cout<<"Enter an age:";
 cin>>age;
 cout<<endl;
}

void initialize ( char name[],int *age)
{
 name[0]='\0'; 
 *age=0; }
void print ( const char name[],const int age )
{
 cout<<"The Value stored in variable name is :"
   <<name<<endl
  <<"The Value stored in variable  age is :"
   <<age<<endl<<endl;
}

void growOlder(const char name[],int *age)
{
 cout<< name <<" has grown one year older\n\n";
 *age++;
}
bool comparePeople (const char *name1,const int *age1,
     const char *name2,const int *age2)
{

return(*age1==*age2 && !strcmp(name1,name2));

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `name` parameter of your `input()` function is a pointer to `const char`.  `const` means you can't modify it, so if you need to modify it, it needs not to be const.

That said, to *really* fix it, use `std::string` wherever you currently use `char[]`s and `char*`s and consider returning objects instead of using out-parameters; this will make your code much less error prone and easier to follow and understand.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol '>>' is an operator. The writer of the String class included this operator to only take primitive types and of course the String class type.

You have two options:

1. Convert the char array to a string
2. Overload the '>>' operator to take char arrays and output it as you like

Look up overloading operator if you really want to have fun.